# Simplify a sum of harmonic numbers

Tags: summation, harmonic-numbers

I am dealing with a sum of harmonic numbers:
$$
\frac{1}{n-j+1}\sum_{\ell=n-j+2}^{n}\frac{1}{\ell}, \;\;\;2\le j\le n.
$$
I wonder if it is possible to simplify it further. Or, is it related to a Riemann sum? (when $n$ is large). Please give me some hints or references. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you aiming for, a good approximation, a useful exact formula?

Comment: WA says $$\psi ^{(0)}(n+1)-\psi ^{(0)}(-j+n+2)$$ the Poly-Gamma function.

Comment: Thank you! I just realized that I want to find an approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is about the limit when $n\mapsto \infty $:

We have $$\sum_{l=n-j+2}^n\frac1l=\sum_{l=1}^{j-1}\frac1{l+n-j+1}=H_{2n-j+1}-H_{n-j+1}$$

Then

$$\lim_{n\mapsto \infty}\frac{1}{n-j+1}\sum_{l=n-j+2}^n\frac1l=\lim_{n\mapsto \infty}\frac{H_{2n-j+1}-H_{n-j+1}}{n-j+1}$$

Clearly, the denominator blows to infinity much faster than the numerator, so the limit is zero.